# Can u explain how to export & import the hive HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0?

Tags: 2010

Error Message : "Share point server is not installed"

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the SharePoint product install properly. There is more to it than just putting files in the 14 folder (we are not supposed to say 'hive' anymore). If you only need SharePoint Foundation you can download this from Microsoft - the licence to use SharePoint Foundation is included in your Windows Server licencing.

URL to download SharePoint installer (about 170Mb):

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=49c79a8a-4612-4e7d-a0b4-3bb429b46595&displaylang=en#QuickDetails